# C tips and tricks explanation

Tags: c++

Can you explain me which is the mechanism behind the next code samples (I think I know but I need second opinion):

1)--------------------------

```
using namespace std;

int * f(int x) {
  return &x;
}

int * g(int x, int y) {
  return &y;
}

int * h(int x, int y, int z) {
  return &z;
}

int main() {
  cout << *f(42) << endl;
  int * y1 = g(43, 44);
  int * y2 = g(45, 46);
  cout << *y1 << ", " << *y2 << endl;
  int * z1 = h(47, 48, 49);
  int * z2 = h(50, 51, 52);
  cout << *z1 << ", " << *z2 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

2)--------------------------

```
int *a, *b;

void f(int x) {
  int i[3];
  i[0] = x;
  i[1] = x + 1;
  i[2] = x + 2;
  a = i;
}  

void g(int x) {
  int i[3];
  i[0] = x;
  i[1] = x + 1;
  i[2] = x + 2;
  b = i;
}  

int main() {
  f(1);
  printf("a = {%d,%d,%d}\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
  g(2);
  printf("a = {%d,%d,%d}\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
}
```

3)--------------------------

```
int main() {
  char * hello = "hello, world!" + 3;
  char * charstring = 'h' + "ello, world!";

  printf("hello=%s, charstring=%s.\n", hello, charstring);
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: please format your code with code sample utility

Comment: So what does it do? You say you think you know it :)

Comment: removed tips-and-tricks tags. I don't see anything there that is a tip nor a trick.

Comment: You post a huge piece of code and ask "what's the mechanism" behind it? Well, that code can be run - that's the mechanism and you should be more specific in your question.

Comment: The "mechanism", if you can call it that, seems to be a reliance on some particular toolchains Undefined Behavior

Comment: 3 kinds of UB.  That's all to say.

Comment: Could be some kind of "buffer overrun" perhaps.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.

Comment: Is this a troll, or a homework assignment?

Comment: Ok, sorry people, my first post on this website. Next time I will be more specific and I will use proper code formatting. What I wanted to ask was what is the exact mechanism behind C++ heap and stack management. I said I know smth and that is: when you return from the function, by destroying the stack variables it means to make the memory available for further usage and not changing its content to a default value.Thus, after getting out from the function, it seems that the values still remain in the freed memory. I was confused by cout << *y1 << ", " << *y2 << endl; in first code after run

Comment: Daniel dear, don't feel so offended. I read your comments and you look very irritated about everything. It is not a homework and it is nothing about trolling. I found the answers below, now I thank you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would expect those programs to crash or do other weird things when you run them.

Example 1: The functions `f`, `g` and `h` are returning the memory addresses of their arguments. Note that those arguments are stored on the stack, and when the functions return, the stack is unwound and the addresses will not be valid anymore. You could get lucky and the value will still be there, but you could just as well have the program crash or return some random value that's not the value that you passed to the function.

Example 2: The functions `f` and `g` set the global variables `a` and `b` to the addresses of local variables declared in the functions. Just like in the first example, those local variables will be gone when the functions return, leaving `a` and `b` pointing to something invalid.

Example 3: This is doing weird pointer arithmetic. `hello` will probably point to the address of the text plus 3, so you'd probably get "lo, world!" printed for this (but it could also be different, depending on how pointer arithmetic works on your particular platform). The case with `charstring` is similar, only here you add `'h'` (ASCII value 104 - so you're adding 104 to the pointer). This will most likely crash the program.

Comment: If you expect these programs to crash, then you don't understand "undefined behavior." Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: @Daniel **in practice**, "undefined behaviour" often means that the program crashes, or does other weird things. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Jesper: undefined behavior means that the language does not require any particular behavior. It isn't required to crash, or do a "weird" thing, or anything else for that matter. It doesn't mean anything else. For example, in arasmussen's answer he thinks that the first program sample will "crash the program" but that isn't the case in many, if not most, environments.

Comment: @Daniel: You're talking about the **theoretical** meaning of "undefined behaviour", I'm talking about what it most often means **in practice**.

Comment: @Jesper: No "theoretical" about it. I'm talking about the *actual* meaning of "undefined behavior" you are talking about what you happen to have noticed in your environment. None of the three programs crash in my environment for example. Anybody who expects any of the three samples to crash simply because they have undefined constructs in them is going to be disappointed.

Comment: Indeed, this is why I posted this in the first place. I had the same accurate results each time I run the programs and even if I restarted my IDE (VS2008). Indeed, it is depended on my system and IDE, but still I was confused (especially about  cout << *y1 << ", " << *y2 << endl; in the first example after I run it several times).

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a little easier for a beginner to understand these concepts if you explain step by step what is happening in the background.

1.

```
cout << *f(42) << endl; // Call f with the value 42
int * f(int x) {        // Push an integer, x, on the stack (x = 42)
   return &x;           // Return a pointer to var x
}                       // Pop x off the stack
               // Pointer now points to a memory address that is unallocated, 
               // which will crash the program when it tries to use that memory, 
               // which it does with cout
```

2.

```
f(1);              // Call f with the value 1
void f(int x) {    // Push an integer, x, on the stack (x = 1)
   int i[3];       // Declare an int* with space for 3 vals (local! stack!)
   i[0] = x;       // Define values of the array
   a = i;          // Set a equal to i, beginning of array
}                  // i is now out of scope, and since it was declared as locally,
                   // rather than with malloc (or new in c++), it is on the stack
                   // and has now been popped off, so a points to a memory address
                   // that the OS *should* have marked as inaccessible
```

3.

```
char * hello = "hello, world!" + 3;        // hello is a char*, a pointer that
                                           // points to the beginning of an array
                                           // of characters. Adding 3 will increment
                                           // the pointer three characters after the
                                           // first character.
char * charstring = 'h' + "ello, world!";  // charstring is a char*, a pointer that
                                           // points to the beginning of an array
                                           // of characters. This time, it would point
                                           // to "ello, world!". However, the addition
                                           // of 'h' will shift the character position
                                           // by 104 characters because that is the 
                                           // value of ascii 'h'.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Why I posted them is because: 1) cout << *f(42) << endl; from the example 1; 2) because of the results of the printf-s from example 2 which gives the results in such a manner that is seems a is ponting to the same locations of memory but with different results; 3)I did not understand why charstring will have the value "e"